# ASP .NET link to a pdf from databound grid

Tags: asp.net, pdf, hyperlink

My databound fields show the date, type, score and grade.  I have added a View PDF column using the following code.

```
enter code here

<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Text="View PDF"    
onclientclick='redirect()'> 
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

New Code 3-3-2016
<asp:GridView id="gvInspection" runat="server"    
DataSourceID="dsInspectionHistory"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
Width="100%" Height="1px"
GridLines="None" PageSize="25"
BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#DFE3C7" ForeColor="Black"/>
<Columns>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Inspection_Date" HeaderText="Date" 
SortExpression="Inspection_Date" DataFormatString="{0:MMM d yyyy}" 
ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceType" HeaderText="Inspection Type" 
SortExpression="ServiceType" ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="192px"/>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="192px"/>
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Score" HeaderText="Score" SortExpression="Score" 
ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Grade" HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="Grade" 
ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="96px"/>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="96px"/>
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report(s)">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Text="View PDF"    
CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Serial_Number") %>' OnClick="LinkButton_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle horizontalalign="Center" width="64px"/>
<HeaderStyle horizontalalign="Center" width="64px"/>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

<EmptyDataTemplate>
    No Inspections To Date
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView></td></tr>
```

My goals are first to only show the View PDF link if there is PDF found that matches the serial number which is part of the recordset.  Then, if the View PDF is clicked, open the associated PDF.  Please assume the PDFs are stored locally.

I appreciate any help.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to write your logic in databound event

Comment: How do I check if a PDF exists?  Most of the data comes from a SQL query, but the PDFs are saved locally.

Comment: File.Exists... you can Google for more information

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the serial number as a command argument of the link button on the click event. Something like this maybe:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Text="View PDF" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("SerialNumber") %>' OnClick="LinkButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    var serial_number = linkButton.CommandArgument;
    var pdf_path = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/PDF/FILE/LOCATION/{0}.pdf", serial_number));

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(pdf_path))
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.TransmitFile(pdf_path);
    }
}
```

VB version

```
Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim linkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim serial_number = linkButton.CommandArgument
    Dim pdf_path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/PDF/FILE/LOCATION/{0}.pdf", serial_number))

    If System.IO.File.Exists(pdf_path) Then
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testing.pdf")
        response.TransmitFile(pdf_path)
        response.End()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Do I save the LinkButton_onclick in the aspx.vb or someplace else?

Comment: Also getting a few errors.  For example, the first line says "End of statement expected."  For each var it says "Declaration expected."  On the If

Comment: On the if it says "Statement cannot appear outside of a method body."

Comment: Yes the `LinkButton_Click` event would go in the aspx.vb page. Sorry, I did not know this was in VB, which is probably why you are getting errors, because this is written in c#. I will add the VB equivalent.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I got the page to render without error.  To test the LinkButton_Click what would I change so it looks at a local folder like "C:\Reports?"

Comment: Actually I don't think the path is the problem.  I have added a PDF (DA1562778.PDF) in the reports folder and verified the following server path.  Path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CHA.RestaurantGrade\Reports\{0}.pdf"     The name DA1562778 matches the serial number I see in the data grid.  When I click on the View PDF link the screen seems to try and execute the code, but does not open the PDF.

Comment: Try adding `response.end()` after the TransmitFile and see if that helps

Comment: No change.  When I hover over the link I noticed the link shows  "javascript:_dopostback"  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, was this supposed to show me a link regardless of whether there is an associated PDF?

Comment: The `javascript:_dopostback` is a .NET Web Forms thing that should have the name of the click event as parameter which tells it to fire that `LinkButton_Click` event. I think your problem maybe with the `TransmitFile` section. I have updated the VB code above and added a `response.AppendHeader` which may help you out. You can set the file name to whatever you want.

Comment: If you wanted to hide the link if the PDF doesn't exist then you could probably use the GridView ItemDataBound event (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)). In that event check to see if the PDF exists if it doesn't, then set the `LinkButton` to `Visible = false`

Comment: Tried the following code unfortunately the same result.  The PDF doesn't open nor does it download.                                                                          If System.IO.File.Exists(pdf_path) Then
            Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DA1562778.pdf")
            response.TransmitFile(pdf_path)
            response.End()
        End If

Comment: Do you get any errors on screen or does just nothing happen at all?? Could you try setting a breakpoint in Visual Studio on the `LinkButton_Click` event?

Comment: Nothing happens.  I would like to set breakpoints, but don't know how.  Debugging was so much easier in VB6.

Comment: In Visual Studio, click in the margin on the left on the line where the `LinkButton_Click` event starts and you should get a big red dot which symbolizes your breakpoint. Now hit the green play button and you site should launch. Go click on you LinkButton and Visual Studio should pop up with your line that you set the breakpoint highlighted in yellow. Use the f10 bbutton to step through the code line by line. I am kinda suspect that the event isn't even firing. Are you using any `UpdatePanels`?

Comment: I am getting a message saying "...because integrated windows authentication is not enabled."  Is that an IIS setting?  I searched for panels and didn't find any.  Is there something else I should search for?

Comment: Ok I was able to get the debug to work.  When I click the View PDF link the code always goes to the Page_Load event.  This happens when I click any of the rows in the grid.  I have added the ASP code to my original post so you can see the columns created.

Comment: Remove the `onclientclick='redirect()'` from your `LinkButton` and make sure you have the `OnClick="LinkButton_Click"` on your `LinkButton` Like in my example code above

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have see a redirect in the ASP.

Comment: I am stumped.  For some reason the LinkButton won't execute the LinkButton_Click event.  Every click goes to the page load event and refreshes the grid.

Comment: I will try to make a working example for you in a bit to see it helps

Comment: Does the VS or .NET framework have any impact?  This application is old and I believe was written on the 2.5 framework.

Comment: You should still be able to achieve what you are trying to do in the older .NET framework

Comment: [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/linktopdfdemo) is a small VB project in .NET 2.0 demoing this solution. I am binding the `GridView` to a fake dataset I create with just 2 rows. 1 row has a PDF and should show the "View PDF" `LinkButton` and should download the PDF when you click it. The other row has a PDF that doesn't exist so the "View PDF" button won't be shown.

Comment: One difference I see is my VB code does not have the rowdatabound code.  Adding that I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  The debugger stops in the rowdatabound code and highlights the Dim serial_number = linkButton.CommandArgument line.

Comment: Do you have `CommandArgument='<%#Bind("SerialNumber") %>'` on your LinkButton? The RowDataBound part is just for hiding or showing the LinkButton if the PDF exists or not

Comment: Yes.  I see that on the ASP linkbutton.

Comment: Oh, this line in the RowDataBound: `Dim linkButton As LinkButton = e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton")` "LinkButton" has to be the ID of the LinkButton. In my demo the ID="LinkButton" and in your code its ID="LinkButton4". Make sure the ID's are the same.

Comment: Appears to be working as far as showing only the link if the PDF is there.  However, when I click the View PDF it still doesn't go to the linkbutton_click event.

Comment: I noticed the link doesn't seem to behave like a link.  Normally if I am hovering over the link and right-click I am given the option to open the link in a new window.  I don't see those options when I right-click the View PDF link in Internet Explorer.  I do see them in Chrome.

Comment: I have rechecked the code and rebuilt the solution, but the View PDF code doesn't execute the LinkButton_OnClick code.

Comment: For whatever reason your click event is being attached. Make sure it spelled correctly on both your aspx page and the code behind .vb file. Maybe trying creating a new event like `LinkButton4_Click`. Can you get any other event attached to your LinkButton?

Comment: Since you said the `RowDataBound` event is firing you could try attaching your click event in that event. Like this: `AddHandler linkButton.Click, AddressOf Me.LinkButton_Click`. Make sure `LinkButton_Click` event is also in you code behind vb file

Comment: I copied the linkbutton and placed it outside the <td> tag and changed the ID from 4 to 5.  When I click that link it tries to fire the rowcreated event.  Is there something about the gridview that it needs to fire those first then try to pass the serial number?

Comment: I noticed when I recreated the linkbutton outside the grid there is a Handles added to the protected sub line.    Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click                                                                       When I try to add the Handles to the current code it says "Handles Clause requires a WithEvents variable."  However, when I type Handles  LinkButton4 is not listed.

Comment: The javascript View PDF shows javascript:__doPostBack('gvInspection$ctl02$LinkButton4','')                    Is there something missing?  I see the target, but no argument.  Is the argument needed?

Comment: Would you be able to send me your `.aspx` and `.aspx.vb` files that have the `GridView`?

Comment: Sure.  Here is the aspx - http://www.filedropper.com/details_3     Here is the aspx.vb http://www.filedropper.com/detailsaspx

Comment: Couple of notes.  in design when I double-click on the View PDF link it creates a gvInspection_SelectedIndexChanged event in the VB.  When I go to LinkButton_Click, right-click and select Go To Definition it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: I got your code working on my computer and PDF is downloading when I click the "View PDF" LinkButton. One thing I think you need to do is wrap all the code in your `Page_Load` event with an `IsPostBack` check. See [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f880c3f2c5c00b9c7aef) for an example of what I am talking about. You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) to see an explanation of `IsPostBack` and why it is used.

Comment: Also, to answer your question about not seeing the argument on the LinkButton - you won't see it. It is part of the ViewState and won't render out on the page. You can see the ViewState on the page if you View Source of the page then find a hidden input with the id `__VIEWSTATE`

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first things I tried.  Still only executes the page load event.  Is there something about the databind happening at the same time that prevents the onclick?

Comment: I think I see the problem

Comment: See this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c79978e30d31b1044d88). You need to move your code from `gvInspection_RowCreated` to the `gvInspection_RowDataBound` event (you can probably remove `gvInspection_RowCreated` altogether) and comment out the `.Attributes.Add("onclick", ...` code. That `onclick` javascript event is preventing the click event in your code behind from firing.

Comment: The view pdf link is working, but now the refresh or update is not working. The upper grid shows multiple results.  When a user clicks on a row the page updates and shows data in a lower grid that pertains to the row selected in the upper grid.

Comment: If I uncomment the attributes.add that functionality returns, but as you pointed I lose the the View PDF functionality.

Comment: Yes you are attaching a javascript `onclick` event to the table row which will always fire before your LinkButton click event. This row `onclick` event is redirecting the page to itself with a bunch of querystring parameters which you are probably using to help bind the other grids. With this setup you won't be able to have any clickable elements (buttons, links) inside your row because this row `onclick` event will always redirect the page before any other click events can fire. Does this make sense?

Comment: Client-side events (i.e. javascript onclick) will always fire before any Server-side events (i.e. `LinkButton_Click`). You are also experiencing event propagation because you have a table row with an event attached and a **nested** LinkButton with its own event. Both will fire when you click "View PDF" and the client-side event will always fire first... which is redirecting the page

Comment: I was afraid it was something like that.  Any suggestions?  Could I wrap the javascript in an if/then?  Would it be possible to put the View PDF in its own grid?

Comment: Why do all events on the page seem to run the javascript?  I created a button outside the grid and the code still executes the rowcreated event.

Comment: The quickest and easiest solution I could think of in your situation is to add a new column at the front of your upper grid that has something like a RadioButton in it. Then create a click event for it to do what you were doing in your RowCommand event to bind the lower 2 grids. Then you could remove your RowCommand event and have the View PDF and row select separated. just a tought

Comment: Luckily I was able to convince the customer to use a thumbnail/link that exists outside the gridview.  Thank you for all your help.  Leaned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to execute a linkbutton event because the javascript runs first.  Please see comments for more information.  Changed to a hyperlink event that exists outside the grid but still uses data from the grid.